# Multiple matches for bash regex behaving strangely?

Tags: regex, bash, xml-parsing

```
string="<tag>First Tag</tag>Some random text <tag>Second Tag</tag>More random text<tag>Third Tag</tag>"

pattern='<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>' 

if [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]; then 
    parsedMatch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo -e "$parsedMatch"
fi

Output : First Tag</tag>Some random text <tag>Second Tag</tag>More random text<tag>Third Tag

Expected output : <tag>First Tag</tag>
```

In this example, both BASH_REMATCH[0] and BASH_REMATCH[1] are the same.
I know of other regular expressions libraries but I am puzzled as to why this behaves this way?

Edit : Changed the pattern to make it ungreedy and it still not working. This behavior exists only in linux/bash so you need to test it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It behaves so because `.*` is greedy in pattern matching and matches as much as possible.

so use another regex like

```
(<tag>[^<]*</tag>)


string="<tag>First Tag</tag>Some random text <tag>Second Tag</tag>More random text<tag>Third Tag</tag>"

pattern='(<tag>[^<]*</tag>)'

if [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]; then
    parsedMatch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo -e "$parsedMatch"
fi
```

produce the output as

```
<tag>First Tag</tag>
```

**Explanation :**

`<tag>` matches starting `<tag>`

`[^<]*` matches anything another than `<`

`</tag>` matches ending `</tag>`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pA8jC6/1)

**EDIT**

Bash uses POSIX.2 regular expression , which does not support a non-greedy Kleene star

Comment: Your regex does not match if there is a nested tag.

Comment: @RamboRamon It wont but it is apt for the string OP has provided

Comment: Can you explain why ungreedy won't work as in (.*?) ? The ungreedy just makes more sense as far as parsing goes for me. The [^<]* will only work within tags.

Comment: It doesnt work because bash uses POSIX.2 regular expression , which does not support a non-greedy Kleene star.

Comment: It seems the greedy cannot be used and only the alternative regex would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work nice.

use this regex :  `<tag(?: [^>]+)?>((?:(?!<\/?tag[ >]).)*)<\/tag>`

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/nC1dO8/2

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but you should try it in a linux/bash terminal, since you will get different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the greedyness of the * with an appended ?. By default it es greedy and with an appended ? it is not. So try `<tag>(.*?)</tag>` as pattern.

Comment: Tried it and still the same output.